# Laravel 8 - SQL Server Date Type (Not Datetime) Parsing Error

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I want to format `date` where I get from SQL Server where data type is `date` (not `datetime`).

I have tried add date casting in model like this:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'date' => 'date:Y',
    ];
}
```

but there is an error:

> Could not parse 'Apr 20 2021 12:00:00:AM': DateTime::__construct():
> Failed to parse time string (Apr 20 2021 12:00:00:AM) at position 20
> (:)

When I change data type in SQL Server to `datetime`, there was worked perfectly.

I have tried any parsing method (in accessor) use Carbon or `date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date))`, there still error when data type is `date` but working well when data type is `datetime`.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I create an accessor to manipulate the `date` string and than format it.

```
public function getDateAttribute($date)
{
    $date = explode(' ', $date);
    return date('Y', strtotime($date[1].$date[0].$date[2]));
}
```